# How I could return or save value into a temp with a callback function in module mysql in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, callback

I used mysql module on npm but when I need return value when I select 1 record I can't catch it. Can you have me catch it because when I use console.log with it. I can see the value but when I use variable or return it. I just have undefine :(.

I need return result but I can't do it is normally :(.

```
var selectSQL = function(accountItems) {
    con.query('call sp_compareAccount(?)', accountItems.email, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        result[0][0]._email;
    });
}
```

Comment: can you show me the value of result variable.

Comment: result is a email value but I can't return or save it into a temp variable :(

Comment: @HirenS. Can you help me plz ?